# Running Groovy tests on Java and Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, groovy, junit

I created a JHipster (Spring Boot) application, but I want to use Groovy for test classes since I can take advantage of the Power Assert that comes native in Groovy.

The problem is that I'm getting an `[ERROR] There was an error in the forked processgroovy/lang/GroovyObject` when trying to run the tests using `mvn test`

In the Pom I added

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

As well as

Comment: I am no maven user, but i'd assume you have to add a groovy depedency to your test configuration as well - this is just the compiler for groovy.

Comment: Including more of the error (`mvn -X` or `mvn --debug`) might give you some better answers.